# Python: Print horizontally lists with specified space in between

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

I have three lists. List1, List2 andList3 and I want to print them horizontally.

```
List1=["Xel", "Mba", "Khol"]
List2=["234", "987", "567"]
List3=["DEF","POL","ZES"]
```

```
for j in range(0, len(List1)):
    print("{:>4}   {:>4}   {:>4}\n".format(List1[j],List2[j], List3[j]))

#The code that I use give me this result:

Xel    234     DEF

Mba     987     POL

Khol    567     ZES
```

#The result that I expect is:

```
Xel   mba   Khol  
234   987    567
DEF   POL    ZES
```

Thank you for your help !

Comment: So you really just want to print the list regularly!? `List1[0],List1[1], List1[2]`!?

Comment: Something like `for row in [List1, List2, List3]: print(*(f"{elem:>4}" for elem in row), end='\n')`?

Comment: Thank you @BRemmelzwaal your solution seems good but I do not have the "4 spaces" in between each column.

Comment: Because `:>4` performs right alignment. Do you just want four spaces?

Comment: It's the both that I wanted to have; rigth alignment and 4 four spaces between the columns

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the comments you've provided, I think this is what you're looking for (albeit pretty ugly):

```py
List1 = ["Xel", "Mba", "Khol"]
List2 = ["234", "987", "567"]
List3 = ["DEF", "POL", "ZES"]

Lists = [List1, List2, List3]
longest = [max(len(row[i]) for row in Lists) for i in range(len(Lists[0]))]  # get longest item from each column

for row in Lists: 
    print((4*" ").join(f"{elem:>{longest[i]}}" for i, elem in enumerate(row)))  # join with right justification with 4 spaces
```

Output:

```py
Xel    Mba    Khol
234    987     567
DEF    POL     ZES
```

Comment: Thank you @B Remmelzwaal, this is what I wanted to do !!

Answer (score 0):

You can do it pretty simply like so:

```
for items in [List1, List2, List3]:
    print("   ".join(items)) #Adjust spacing here between "", or use \t for a tab
```

Answer (score 0):

you can do it this way, though it is not the most efficient way

```
for row in range(0, len(List1)):
    print(f"{List1[row]}", end="    ")
print("")
for row in range(0, len(List1)):
    print(f"{List2[row]}", end="    ")
print("")
for row in range(0, len(List1)):
    print(f"{List3[row]}", end="    ")
print("")
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).